# Paypal buy now button passing some variables but not all

Tags: php, paypal

I have a problem where I am creating a Paypal Buy Now Button for a client's website. The first name, last name and email address and item name are going though, but the billing address nor the price are going through. Very strange for what should be a straightforward process. Here is my code:

```
$invoicenumber = $row['InvoiceNumber'];
$totalquantity = $row['TotalQuantity'];
$totalprice = $row['TotalPrice'];
$costofshipping = $row['CostOfShipping'];
$firstname = $row['FirstName'];
$lastname = $row['LastName'];
$billingstreetaddress = $row['BillingStreetAddress'];
$billingapartmentnumber = $row['BillingApartmentNumber'];
$billingcity = $row['BillingCity'];
$billingstate = $row['BillingState'];
$billingzipcode = $row['BillingZipCode'];
$emailaddress = $row['EmailAddress'];
echo "<form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_s-xclick'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='business' VALUE='payments@companyname.com'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='invoice' VALUE='$invoicenumber'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='undefined_quantity' VALUE='$totalquantity'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='item_name' VALUE='CompanyNamePurchase'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='amount' VALUE='$totalprice'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='shipping' VALUE='$costofshipping'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='currency_code' VALUE='USD'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='first_name' VALUE='$firstname'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='last_name' VALUE='$lastname'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='address1' VALUE='$billingstreetaddress'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='address2' VALUE='$billingapartmentnumber'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='city' VALUE='$billingcity'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='state' VALUE='$billingstate'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='zip' VALUE='$billingzipcode'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='lc' VALUE='US'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='email' VALUE='$emailaddress'>
input type='hidden' name='hosted_button_id' value='paypalclientnumber'>
<input type='image' id='paypalsubmitbutton' style='top:750px;left:65%;position:absolute;'     src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif' border='0'    name='submit' alt='PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!'>
<img alt='' border='0' src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif'    width='1' height='1'>
</form>";
```

/* And this is the source code - as you can see no invoice number goes through, price and quantity are zero, and the address is there, but does not go through to paypal. The cost of shipping is also there. */

```
<form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_s-xclick'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='business' VALUE='payments@companyname.com'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='invoice' VALUE=''>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='undefined_quantity' VALUE='0'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='item_name' VALUE='CompanyNamePurchase'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='amount' VALUE='0.00'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='shipping' VALUE='7.00'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='currency_code' VALUE='USD'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='first_name' VALUE='Multigrain'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='last_name' VALUE='Cheerios'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='address1' VALUE='2 Spoonful Way'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='address2' VALUE='myemailaddress@email.com'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='city' VALUE='Brooklyn'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='state' VALUE='New York'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='zip' VALUE='11203'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='lc' VALUE='US'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='email' VALUE=''>
<input type='hidden' name='hosted_button_id' value='paypalidjumbledletters&#s'>
<input type='image' id='paypalsubmitbutton'     style='top:750px;left:65%;position:absolute;' src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif' border='0' name='submit' alt='PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!'>
<img alt='' border='0' src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif' width='1' height='1'>
</form>
```

Comment: Let me guess... the option `paypalsubmitbutton=paypalclientnumber` is the missing one? Still, this isn't the right forum for this question I don't think.

Comment: Can you show us the actual code getting output in the source of the page instead of the PHP generating it?  From what you're showing/saying I would assume your PHP valuse aren't getting populated the way you think they are.

Comment: Here is the source code. It looks like the address is definitely there, so why isn't it showing up in paypal checkout? The price however is showing up as 0, though that variable is definitely correct. I have a select sql query right above the paypal button.

Comment: And the variables should definitely be getting populated, especially if some of the variables are. Already checked to make sure my column names were correct in the variables.

Comment: I'd make sure the price variable is actually being set to the correct value.

Comment: Just checked again. Also I tried using my own realistic name and address and still no luck. The only values coming through to Paypal checkout are first name, last name, email address - no quantity, price, shipping, invoice number or physical address. Thank you for your help so far, I appreciate it.

Comment: I found the solution, use an unhosted button. This has been suggested by other Stack Overflow members in similar questions, just confirming it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to making sure that the button is an unhosted button, if you are having trouble passing address variables, make sure the state is abbreviated, i.e., MA instead of Massachusetts. This has been the solution for me.